Using Taylor's theorem to prove the inequality
I must prove the following inequality, relying on Taylor's theorem.
$\lvert sin(6x+5)-(6x+5)\rvert\leq \frac{\lvert6x+5\rvert^3}{6}$
I was able to successfully find the Taylor's polynomial evaluation of $sin(6x+5)$ around $x_0=-\frac{5}{6}$ however I haven't found much success deriving any meaningful conclusion from it. Any help would be most appreciated.
If possible, I would be most elated to have received some generic guidance which would assure I am able to grasp the concept without the restraints of this problem.

I would try to show  $|\sin t-t|\le{|t|^3\over 6}$ and then subsitute $t=6x+5.$

You can get that error estimate from the Lagrange remainder for the at-most-second degree Taylor polynomial of $\sin(6x+5)$ at $x_0=-5/6$. The key is that the third derivative has a convenient bound.
I'll do a simpler case here, instead of doing your actual problem for you: the at-most-first degree Taylor polynomial of $\cos(x)$ at $x=0$ is $\cos(0)+\cos'(0)(x-\cos(0))=1+0 \cdot x = 1$. So the Lagrange remainder says $\cos(x)-1=\frac{\cos''(t)}{2!} (x-0)^2 = \frac{-\cos(t)}{2!} x^2$ for some $t$ between $0$ and $x$. So $|\cos(x)-1| \leq \frac{x^2}{2}$ since $|\cos(t)|$, whatever it is, is at most $1$.
In my experience, the Lagrange remainder is the most commonly used result for estimating a Taylor remainder, at least as the first attempt. Occasionally I have needed a better estimate than it can give and then there are other remainder theorems such as the integral remainder theorem.

Could you please elaborate? I appreciate the answer but my brain is slow to comprehend this concenpt

@Sorer Let me know if my new second paragraph helps.

It does. I was now able to solve the original problem and another problem similar to it. Much obliged!!!
